How to align and concatenate parts of string using {fmt}
I want to format 5 strings like:
   int half { 32 };
    string middle { "[===]" };
    string str = fmt::format("{0:<{half}}{1:<}{4}{2:<{half}}{3:<}",
                      "lpad",
                      "left",
                      "rpad",
                      "right",
                      middle,
                      fmt::arg("half", half));
    cout << str << endl;

What I want:
lpadleft                            [===]rpadright

And what I get:
lpad                            left[===]rpad                            right

How can I reach desired? Thanks in advance!

This documentation is all available on cppreference so do some research effort. Or look for a "std::format cheat sheet" e.g. https://dev.to/hackingcpp/fmt-library-overview-cheat-sheets-53ap
